# How to take a precised value as input?

Tags: c++, precision

```
cout << setprecision (2) << fixed;
cin>>R;
cout<<R;
```

Now if I set **R = 2.3456**,
this gives me **2.34**. 
But in calculation **R** works as **2.3456** if i take this number as input.
But I want to take **2.34** as input after doing precision.
How do i do that?

Comment: Your precision works on the output, not input. That is why the value is still present in "full" precision.

Comment: You could multiply by 100, floor it, divide by 100 and then go on, but be warned of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to take input with a specific precision. Stuffs like `std::setprecision` only works on output streams. You can manually "truncate" extra precision by rounding.

This is an example:

```
double a;
std::cin >> a;
a = std::round(a * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

Be ware that [decimal floating points may not be represented percisely in computers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5958455).

Comment: I get it now :) ty

Comment: @shayer when an answer solves your problem, give it a checkmark instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think the more general method would be :

```
#include <math.h>

double roundTo( double inNumber, int n ) {
   double nn = pow( 10, n );
   // static_cast< dest_type > is more modern and standard way ..
   return static_cast<double>( static_cast<long long>( inNumber * nn ) / nn );
}
```

Comment: The `long` is bad.

Comment: You're surely failing with `1.0e10` (or `1.0e20`, with `long long`), which is obviously inside the range of `double`.